# Using R to download raster files from url that otherwise automatically download?

Tags: r, gis, raster

I'm trying to download doppler radar raster data from the following website: http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/docs/nexrad_composites/

Many of the radar data are PNG's, but I need them in raster format. The website enables downloading of rasters with the following server-side conversion tool: https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/gis/n0r2gtiff.php?dstr=200711010025

Where the end of the url indicates the date and time of the doppler raster that is sought. When you go to the link, it then automatically starts downloading a zip file with the .tif file inside. I need to download a bunch of different dates and times, to the point where I need to automate the process somehow. I've tried this in r with the following code:

```
url = "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/gis/n0r2gtiff.php?dstr=200711010025"

download.file(url,destfile = "temp.zip")
```

However, when I go to open the `temp.zip` file on my computer, it says the file format is invalid. Is something going wrong here because the file automatically downloads at the url? Can anyone please help me to get this one file to download with R in a usable format, so that I can then loop through the dates and times I need?

Answer (score 0):

As it is zip file we need to set `method = 'curl'`,

```
url = "https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/gis/n0r2gtiff.php?dstr=200711010025"
#download the file in your working directory 
download.file(url, paste0('n0r_', sub(".*\\b(\\d+).*", "\\1", url), '.zip'), method = 'curl')
```

Comment: And just a word or so about the `"\\1"` (callback?) as replacement in sub call.

Comment: `\\1` captures the group of numbers